# Tailwind CSS active psuedo class not working for screen readers

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, accessibility, tailwind-css

I created a button utility class for a React button component. The pseudo classes work great with mouse clicks, but the `:active` pseudo class doesn't work when I try to navigate/interact with the button via keyboard.

Here is the config:

```
variants: {
    accessibility: ['responsive', 'hover', 'focus', 'active', 'group-hover'],
    backgroundColor: ['responsive', 'hover', 'focus', 'active']
  },
```

CSS utility classes:

```
.btn-white {
  @apply text-blue-700;
  @apply font-semibold;
  @apply py-2;
  @apply px-4;
  @apply border;
  @apply border-blue-500;
  @apply rounded-full;
}

.btn-white:hover {
  @apply bg-aaBlue; 
  @apply text-white; 
  @apply border-transparent;
}

.btn-white:focus {
  @apply outline-none; 
  @apply shadow-outline;
}

.btn-white:active {
  @apply bg-red-500
}
```

And the React component:

```
<Button 
  onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}
  className='btn-white'
>
  Click me
</Button>
```

Comment: are you pressing the Space key? Just thought I would check as your CSS looks fine.

Comment: Wow, no. I'm an idiot. Space key works but not the enter key. I assumed that enter would be the key for that...I need to go read about screen readers !

Comment: Its a quirk of `:active`, nothing to do with screen readers just plain old HTML and CSS here :-P. You are not an idiot, I have done it at least 3 times in the past 2 years when designing themes wondering why my CSS isn't working ><, hopefully one day I will learn. hehe.